# How to grant administrator privileges in Mac OS X shell script?

Tags: shell, terminal, authorization, admin

```
#!/bin/sh

# The following files are bundled:
#
# 'Wiener.dog'
#
#

open -a /Applications/Hot\ Dog.app/Contents/MacOS/Hot Dog ~/Documents/Broiler\ Cooked/Wiener.dog
```

The shell script executes fine, although it always asks for admin authorization -- how do I skip that part so I don't have to deal with touching the wiener? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can try setting the *setuid* bit, and change the file's owner to root:

```
sudo chown root /Applications/Hot\ Dog.app/Contents/MacOS/Hot\ Dog
sudu chmod 4755 /Applications/Hot\ Dog.app/Contents/MacOS/Hot\ Dog
```

The first line sets the **Hot Dog** application to belong to root.
The second line sets the *setuid* bit, which has the application run as the user it belongs to, even if launched by some other user.

As far as I know Mac OS doesn't allow *setuid* on shell scripts.

You should note, however, that this changes permissions for the **Hot Dog** application, and the change is permanent. Whoever has access to this application and tries to run it will run it with Administrator privileges. If you are the only user of this computer you should be OK, but if this is a multi-user machine, and the **Hot Dog** application does potentially dangerous stuff, you should be aware that everyone can use it.

You can limit the impact by defining a custom group, say *hotdog*, put yourself in this group, and use instead:

```
sudo chown root:hotdog /Applications/Hot\ Dog.app/Contents/MacOS/Hot\ Dog
sudu chmod 4750 /Applications/Hot\ Dog.app/Contents/MacOS/Hot\ Dog
```

The first line sets the file's ownership to the **root** user and **hotdog** group. The second allows execution by the owner (root) and by whoever is in the **hotdog** group, and no one else. It also sets the *setuid* bit, which means that the application will run with Administrator privileges, even if a non administrator runs it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try, although is the permissions change permanent or just during the lifetime that the script is running?

Comment: The change is permanent. I'll edit my post with some more info.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation, it's very much appreciated. I tried changing the setuid and it does work. Good idea on defining a custom group too -- I'm definitely always weary of giving anything root access; it's kind of a big no-no. Thanks again! ;-)

Comment: I would +1 your answer, although I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: sudo Vs sudo.  (djudo)?